# ipconfig -- port forwarding does not work with Wireguard

Tags: networking, debian, port-forwarding, iptables, wireguard

I have a working WireGuard configuration, and am trying to set up port forwarding to route traffic from the server to the client. I'm trying to do some testing with port 80 -- I have an nginx server on the client that works fine. `10.20.40.2` is the internal IP for the client, `10.20.40.1` is the IP for the server --

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT                                                      
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT                                                              
iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT                                                              
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.20.40.2                                                          
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -p tcp --dport 80 -d 10.20.40.2 -j SNAT --to-source 10.20.40.1
```

I followed [this](https://golb.hplar.ch/2019/01/expose-server-vpn.html) guide in order to port forward, and ran the commands above. They execute without error, but nothing seems to work -- I still get 'Connection refused' when I try to connect to port 80 on the server. I've been trying to find a solution for a few hours, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was eventually solved by removing all the `-i eth0`s from the commands. No idea why this works, I asked some guy on IRC and he told me to.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.20.40.2                                                                  
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT                                                              
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT                                                                      
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT                                                                     
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.20.40.2                                                                  
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -p tcp --dport 80 -d 10.20.40.2 -j SNAT --to-source 10.20.40.1
```